# Can't resolve a variable inside a private method

Tags: java, oop, methods

My IDE (intelliJ) is telling me it can't resolve the variable x in "this.x". Am I doing this correctly?

```
 private Double localTax(){
double x = 0;

    if(grossIncome <= 45000){
        x = (grossIncome * 0.0115);
    }
    else if (grossIncome > 45000){
        x = (45000 * 0.0115);
    }
    return this.x;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  `x` is a local variable for your method.  `this` refers to instance fields, not local variables.  Remove the `this` to get your code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a local variable x. 
 *this.x refers to an instance variable.*

```
public class hello {
  private int x; //this is this.x

  public int foo(int globalIncome){
    int x = globalIncome;
    return x; //returns globalIncome
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you use this.x for a static variable?

Comment: also this.x doesn't refer to global variable. It refers to instance variable.